# How to get all the cucumber scenario steps in before hook?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to access all the cucumber scenario steps in `@before` hook. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried passing the cucumber scenario object in the before hook method but it only provides the basic info like `scenario.getName()`, `scenario.getId()`. What I require is something like `getSteps()` which give me the `List<String>` of all the steps of that particular scenario.

What I am looking for is something like this

```
    @Before("@dev")
public void testcase(Scenario scenario){

    for (Step a : scenario.getSteps()) {
        System.out.println("scenario step = " + a.getText());
    }
}
```

Basically I want the complete scenario information at the beginning of the test execution itself.

If I pass the argument of class cucumber.api.TestCase in the before method then I can access the `getTestSteps()` method but that leads to below exception.

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: When a hook declares an argument it must be of type cucumber.api.Scenario. public void com.thermofisher.bid.spa.kingfisher.ui.steps.Hooks.poc(cucumber.api.TestCase)
```

Comment: What's the full name of Scenario class?

Comment: cucumber.api.Scenario.class

Comment: Have you tried with `TestCase.getTestSteps`?

Comment: Have tried with it but the problem is that the before hook takes only Scenario as agrument. Else it with throw the above mentioned exception. Is there a way i can pass testcase as an argument

Comment: Cucumber will not give you this information. Serenity may have the information available but it would be non-trivial to obtain. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am going so second John on this. If it's for reporting purposes have a look at the plugin infra structure.

Comment: Hi john, so the problem i am trying to solve is to create a manual test case out of the gherkin scenario/feature file and push it to confluence/JIRA using atlassian API's to reduce the manual efforts in our workflow. 
Could you please let me know how to get the information that you are mentioning from serenity ?

Comment: @JohnSmart, think about this: the `Before` hook is used to be called before a scenario is executed. This can be done to log what scenario is being executed. Cucumber also provides a `BeforeStep` hook, but instead of allowing access to the `PickleStepTestStep`, it forces you to either use no arguments or one argument which must also be a Scenario object. This is useless in the context of a Step. One would assume that, if I want to log Step-related information, one would use this hook with a PickleStep argument, so that you can log the step text, line number, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) throws Exception{

    tags = (ArrayList<String>) scenario.getSourceTagNames();
    System.out.println("At Hooks: " + scenario.getId());
    Iterator ite = tags.iterator();

    while (ite.hasNext()) {

        String buffer = ite.next().toString();
        if (buffer.startsWith("<tagOfATestCase>")) {

            Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            TestCase r = (TestCase) f.get(scenario);

            List<PickleStepTestStep> testSteps = r.getTestSteps().stream().filter(x -> x instanceof PickleStepTestStep)
                    .map(x -> (PickleStepTestStep) x).collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (PickleStepTestStep ts : testSteps) {

                System.out.println(ts.getStepText());//will print your test case steps

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java:**

Refer to the `TestCase` interface under `cucumber-jvm/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/runner/TestCase.java`

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/runner/TestCase.java

```
testcase.getTestSteps();
```

*I know the question is not related to ruby, but want to provide the solution in ruby too so that it might help someone looking for the solution in ruby.*

**Ruby:** Will give all the list of steps.

```
scenario.source[1].steps
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't get direct access to the Step data (PickeStepTestStep) because the Cucumber hooks limits your access to the Scenario object, even when using @BeforeStep.

Answer (score 0):

With Cucumber 6.10.3 it is possible to do it, with the following code:

```
Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
f.setAccessible(true);
io.cucumber.core.backend.TestCaseState sc = (io.cucumber.core.backend.TestCaseState) f.get(scenario);          
Field f1 = sc.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
f1.setAccessible(true);
io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestCase testCase = (io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestCase) f1.get(sc);
        
List<PickleStepTestStep> testSteps = testCase.getTestSteps().stream().filter(x -> x instanceof PickleStepTestStep).map(x -> (PickleStepTestStep) x).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (PickleStepTestStep ts : testSteps) {
       System.out.println(ts.getStep().getKeyword() + ts.getStep().getText());
}
```

Imports:

```
import io.cucumber.java8.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.PickleStepTestStep;
import io.cucumber.core.backend.TestCaseState;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Dependencies: (you only need 'cucumber-java8' or 'cucumber-java')

```
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '6.10.3'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '6.10.3'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '6.10.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but does the job for me:

```java
    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        Field delegate = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
        delegate.setAccessible(true);
        TestCaseState state = (TestCaseState) delegate.get(scenario);
        Field testCaseF = state.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
        testCaseF.setAccessible(true);
        TestCase testCase = (TestCase) testCaseF.get(state);
        Field pickle = testCase.getClass().getDeclaredField("pickle");
        pickle.setAccessible(true);
        Pickle pickleState = (Pickle) pickle.get(testCase);
        List<Step> steps = pickleState.getSteps();
        //... your logic here
    }
```

In case the imports are needed:

```
import io.cucumber.core.backend.TestCaseState;
import io.cucumber.core.gherkin.Pickle;
import io.cucumber.core.gherkin.Step;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestCase;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score -1):

Cucumber does not provide you any direct method which grab complete information of a scenario inside the Hook. There is **Scenario interface** which can give you very limited information like scenario name and below are the rest direct methods of this interface.

```
public interface Scenario {
    Collection<String> getSourceTagNames();
    Result.Type getStatus();
    boolean isFailed();
    void embed(byte[] data, String mimeType);
    void write(String text);
    String getName();
    String getId();
    String getUri();
    List<Integer> getLines();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, scenario interface i am already aware of and have tried using it. But that is not solving my purpose as you mentioned, it provides very limited information that's why i posted the question to have a workaround. There are other classes which provides the details of the scenario like cucumber.api.TestCase but the problem is hwo to use them in hooks method.